# Are 得到 and 接受 similar?

Tags: grammar

I saw the previous posts about 接受 and  接收。 But couldn't find information about the difference between 接受 and 得到。 它们的对象可以是抽象的也可以是具体的？ 得到/接受的可以是好的也可以是消极的？ 
Or maybe I just need to memorize the “习惯搭配”？！

Comment: "接受" usually involves a second person(may be implicit or explicit) , from which    you 接受 something.

Comment: For example "接受命运" I think the second person/thing "天" is implicit  in this phrase.

Comment: see dictionaries, 得到：get, obtain,etc,接受：accept,receive, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

得到 is receive, emphasize on the physical action of getting something. 
接受 is more like accept, emphasize on the mental acceptance of something. It can be things related to moral, like 接受批评: I know I am wrong, and I accept the truth that I am wrong. However, 得到（或者 受到）批评 means: the action that I am being blamed by someone.

Answer (score 3):

While similar, they aren't interchangeable. According to the [dictionary](http://yun.dreye.com/dict_new/dict.php),

接受:
to accept; to take; to embrace; to adopt; to bow to
Examples:
他已經接受了我們的邀請。He has accepted our invitation.
山姆因為窮只得接受這份工作。Sam had to take the job because he was broke.

得到:
to obtain; to receive; to acquire; to derive; to earn; to get; to gain
Examples:
他們從政府那裡得到一筆貸款。They obtained a loan from the government.
她應該得到此榮譽。She is worthy to receive such honor.

接受 is passive, such as when you accept gifts or accept a situation. 得到 is for when you actively seek out or ask, and as a result, you received.

Hope this helps!